# Welcome Event not working using discordmongo & discordpy

Tags: mongodb, discord, discord.py, pymongo

so i have a cmd in a cog that suppose to set the welcome channel "welcomec" and from that its supposed to take that info and use it to post the message in the guild welcome channel but doesnt seem to work ngl can anyine help me

edited: after changing it to what RiVen told me i got a new error that I don't understand at all

main code:
welcome: event

```
@fright.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    fright.db = fright.mongo['fright']
    fright.welcome = discordmongo.Mongo(connection_url=fright.db, dbname="welcome")
    dbguild = await fright.welcome.find({"_id": member.guild.id})
    dbchannel = await fright.welcome.find({"welcomec": member.guild.id})
    wguild = fright.get_guild(dbguild)
    wchannl = await fright.fetch_channel(dbchannel)
    await wchannl.send('worksss')
```

error:

```
raise HTTPException(r, data) discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body In channel_id: Value "None
```

Comment: well i did that now im getting this error 
```
raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In channel_id: Value "None" is not snowflake.
```

what the welcome collection look like:
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/904524637298384929/922224866004971660/unknown.png

Answer (score 0):

`NoneType` error means that it doesn't correctly recognize the channel. When you use `get_channel` you are looking for the channel in the bot's cache which might not have your channel. You could use `fetch_channel` instead - which is an API call.

```
wchannl = await fright.fetch_channel(dbchannel)
```

Comment: well i did that now im getting this error 
```
raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In channel_id: Value "None" is not snowflake.
```

[what the welcome collection look like](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/904524637298384929/922224866004971660/unknown.png)

Comment: This means that the `dbchannel` variable is empty. Could you edit or copy your code to somewhere like [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com) (especially include how you created the MongoDB client).

Comment: o btw  i fixed it sorry for not keeping you updated i used a diff and better mongodb wrapper